# Adding a library (ActionBarSherlock) to a project that uses EGit fails

Tags: android, eclipse, git, actionbarsherlock, egit

I have two stub projects 1) No Egit. 2) With EGit enabled.

When I add a library (ActionBarSherlock) to the first this is what I get:
[image]

When I add the same lib to the second, this is what happens when I close and open properties:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Note: the first project is in D:\Dropbox\DBworkspace\testest2 and the second is located in C:\Users\user\git\TESTTEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I moved ActionBarSherlock to the same partition as the project and added it to the project again everything is working.